# Inputting data from url GET into a form and submitting on page load with javascript which then loads an ajax map causes the script to loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, loops, get

I've got a store locator currently on my website - this works by loading an ajax map when the user enters a postcode, this all works fine on the one page that it is on.

The problem I am having is I now want a separate input box on my home page where a user can input their postcode, be redirected to the store locator page and have the map load.

I am sending the postcode from the home page to the store locator page through GET. It then takes the data puts it into the input form and submits it - this all happens on the page load. However when it then starts loading the AJAX, it causes a little refresh(?) which then makes it run the original javascript again and a loop begins.

My code to process the GET data and search is this;

```
<script>
    var getData = new QueryData();              
    var str = jQuery.param( getData );
    var result = str.split("=")[1];
    result = result.replace('+', ' ')
    console.log(result);
    $( "postcode" ).text( result );
    document.getElementById('postcode').value = result;
    document.getElementById("postcodesearch").click();
</script>
```

My AJAX script is the following;

```
bindFindARetailerMapFormValidators: function() {
    $('#findARetailerMapForm').formValidation().on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get the form instance
        var $form = $(e.target);

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#findARetailerResultsOuter").offset().top
        }, 600);
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "block";
        postcode = $('#postcode').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/umbraco/Surface/FindARetailer/PostcodeSearch',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                postcode: postcode
            }),
            success: function (response) {
                $("#findARetailerResults").fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    $("#findARetailerResultsOuter").html(response).fadeIn('fast');

                    document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "none";
                });
                $form.data('formValidation').disableSubmitButtons(false);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                $form.find('.form-error').text(response);
                $form.find('.form-error').fadeIn('slow');
                $form.data('formValidation').disableSubmitButtons(false);
            }
        });
    });
},
```

The form accepting my postcode is;

```
                <form method="post" id="findARetailerMapForm" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="find-near-you-postcode-container">
                            <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
                            <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="Enter Postcode" />
                            <input type="image" id="postcodesearch" src="~/Assets/FindARetailer/search.png" alt="Go" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're not hitting the code that contains your `e.preventDefault()` line.  I think this is because you are nesting all that code in an anonymous function and assigning it to the key `bindFindARetailerMapFormValidators`, but you're not calling that function anywhere. If you look at the example in the documentation for the validation library you're using ([here](http://formvalidation.io/examples/ajax-submit/)), you'll see that they select the form in the scope of the document.ready function and don't nest it in another function.

So I can suggest two possible solutions:

1. Extracting your validation and ajax code from that function:

   ```
   var getData = new QueryData();              
   var str = jQuery.param( getData );
   var result = str.split("=")[1];

   result = result.replace('+', ' ')
   console.log(result);

   $( "postcode" ).text( result );
   document.getElementById('postcode').value = result;
   document.getElementById("postcodesearch").click();

   $('#findARetailerMapForm').formValidation().on('success.form.fv', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       etc...
   ```
2. If you can't do this for some reason, perhaps you can bind the `bindFindARetailerMapFormValidators` variable to a submit event on the form and achieve the same result, like so:

   ```
   $("findARetailerMapForm").on("submit" bindFindARetailerMapFormValidators)
   ```

Though the validation library my interfere with this. Anyway, those are my suggestions. Apologies if I've misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: @btwebsite Thanks for your input - however I've just tried both of your suggested solutions and I'm still hitting a loop before the ajax loads.

Comment: @J.Gill Too bad! Another thing I noticed. You call the jQuery method `.click()` on the submit button, but you did not select it as a jQuery object. Perhabs that is part of the problem. Maybe try `$("#postcodesearch").click()`, or even better, `$("#findARetailerMapForm").submit()`.

Comment: Another thing that may help is if you move the event listener above the code where you trigger it. In other words, the `.click()` or `.submit()` method should be called below the `$('#findARetailerMapForm').formValidation().on('success.form.fv, ...`